# How to add new dictionaries to the large dictionary by changing only people indexes

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a problem because I want to add smaller dictionaries to the large dictionary using a loop. I manage to add dictionaries, which are called 1,2,3, etc. I would like to have these dictionaries preceded by the word "person". Can you do it with one line of code?

This is my actual code:

```
def smaller_dictionaries(number):
    dictionary_consist_of_3_smaller_dictionary ={number:{"surname":None,"name":None,"age":None,"profession":None,"marital status":None} for number in range (1,number)}
    print (dictionary_consist_of_3_smaller_dictionary)
smaller_dictionaries(4)

and this is my output:

{1: {'surname': None, 'name': None, 'age': None, 'profession': None, 'marital status': None}, 2: {'surname': None, 'name': None, 'age': None, 'profession': None, 'marital status': None}, 3: {'surname': None, 'name': None, 'age': None, 'profession': None, 'marital status': None}}
```

as I want to add the prefix "person" in the loop, the program shows that name 'person_' is not defined

```
dictionary_consist_of_3_smaller_dictionary ={person_(number):{"surname":None,"name":None,"age":None,"profession":None,"marital status":None} for number in range (1,number)}

I want to have output in this form:
{peson_1: {'surname': None, 'name': None, 'age': None, 'profession': None, 'marital status': None}, person_2: {'surname': None, 'name': None, 'age': None, 'profession': None, 'marital status': None}, person_3: {'surname': None, 'name': None, 'age': None, 'profession': None, 'marital status': None}}
```

Is it possible to add the prefix "person" in the loop?

Answer (score 0):

The error you get is because Python is considering `person_` as a variable name, hence it raises a [NameError](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#NameError) informing you that is not defined:

> Raised when a local or global name is not found. This applies only to
>   unqualified names. The associated value is an error message that
>   includes the name that could not be found.

One possible solution, with little code, is using [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

```
def smaller_dictionaries(number):
    dictionary_consist_of_3_smaller_dictionary = {
        f'person_{number}': {"surname": None, "name": None, "age": None, "profession": None, "marital status": None} for number in
        range(1, number)}
    print(dictionary_consist_of_3_smaller_dictionary)


smaller_dictionaries(4)
```

**Output**

```
{'person_1': {'surname': None, 'name': None, 'age': None, 'profession': None, 'marital status': None}, 'person_2': {'surname': None, 'name': None, 'age': None, 'profession': None, 'marital status': None}, 'person_3': {'surname': None, 'name': None, 'age': None, 'profession': None, 'marital status': None}}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your are looking for something like this:

```
def smaller_dictionaries(number):
  dictionary_consist_of_3_smaller_dictionary={}
  for i in range(1,number+1):
    key_ = 'person_'+str(i)
    dictionary_consist_of_3_smaller_dictionary[key_] ={"surname":None,"name":None,"age":None,"profession":None,"marital status":None}
```

Output:

```
{'person_1': {'surname': None, 'name': None, 'age': None, 'profession': None, 'marital status': None}, 'person_2': {'surname': None, 'name': None, 'age': None, 'profession': None, 'marital status': None}, 'person_3': {'surname': None, 'name': None, 'age': None, 'profession': None, 'marital status': None}, 'person_4': {'surname': None, 'name': None, 'age': None, 'profession': None, 'marital status': None}}
```